# how do we implement facebook like image grid in post .. using angular material 1.1.0

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm creating an application, in which I want to implement something similar to Facebook posts. I want to create an images grid in the post if there is more then 1 image with angular material . I need little help.

This is like what I want:

[image: Like this type of image grid in my post]

How do I do that in angular material?

Answer (score 0):

The GridList seems to be a good starting point for this application. Have a look at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/gridList

Comment: i have already seen that and tried to implement but it's look little blurry to me. that's why i asked here